# Static folder with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.use(app.static('public'));
server.listen(3000);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I was just trying to fire up very small work project but I got stuck when it came to static content. I have checked other similar threads but I can't find out why it won't work for me. I just get this error:

```
server.use(app.static('public'));
                     ^
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'static'
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't really think out what. Maybe I should go to bed soon enough :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API as of express 3 is you need the plain express module to be separate from your app instance.

```
var express = require('express'); //do NOT invoke the function here
var app = express(); //DO invoke it here to get app
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to use `express.static()`, not `app.static()`. In your example, app was effectively created by

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

However you shortened it to

```
var app = require('express')();
```

Because you did this you don't have any reference to the base express object other than by using `require('express')` again, and this is the reference you need to use static.

You can fix this two ways.

1) Change your beginning code to

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

and your configure to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

2) Simply change the configure to

```
app.use(require('express').static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

However you'd have to do this whenever you reference Express. Note that I haven't tried this option, but I'm assuming it'll work.

I would definately recommend option one. Also, you should probably create the server after you do the configuration and such for the app.