# Type Error when static directory of to an expressJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying expose a `bower_components` directory on my express app and it keep throwing errors.

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'static'

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use("/", app.static(__dirname + "/bower_components"));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *: 3000');
});
```

---

---

### **How do I allow bower components to be visible when i hit my index.html?**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static folder with nodejs and express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317904/static-folder-with-nodejs-and-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express 3's API for this has changed. You need to call `express.static()`, not `app.static()`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/bower_components"));
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317960/406249).